MLE of Uniform($\theta$, $\theta+|\theta|$)
Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from a uniform distribution on the interval $(\theta, \theta+|\theta|)$, where $\theta \in (-\infty, \infty)$, $\theta \neq 0$. I want to find the MLE of $\theta$.
The likelihood of $\theta$ is $$
L(\theta|X_1,...,X_n)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\theta^n}I(\theta<X_{(1)}<X_{(n)}<2\theta), & \theta>0 &  \\
\frac{1}{(-\theta)^n}I(\theta<X_{(1)}<X_{(n)}<0), & \theta<0
\end{cases}$$
By solving the MLE for each cases, I find the MLE of $\theta$ is $$
\hat{\theta} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{X_{(n)}}{2}, & X_{(n)}<2X_{(1)} &  \\
X_{(1)}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I'm not sure if my derivation is correct. Can anyone verify my answer?

Notice that if $x_{(n)}/2>x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}>0$, then the likelihood vanishes. We cannot get such an observation for a uniform distribution on $(\theta,\theta+\lvert\theta\rvert).$ Indeed, if $\theta<0$, then we get a uniform distribution on $(\theta,0)$ hence we cannot have $x_{(n)}>0$, and if $\theta>0$, we have $\theta<x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}/2<\theta<x_{(1)}$, a contradiction.
If $x_{(n)}<0$, indeed, the maximum of the likelihood function is reached at $x_{(1)}$. If $x_{(n)}>0$ then we necessarily have $x_{(n)}/2<x_{(1)}$ hence the maximum is reached at $x_{(n)}/2$. Consequently, the maximum likelihood estimator is given by
$$
\widehat{\theta}= X_{(1)}\mathbf{1}_{X_{(n)}<0}+\frac{X_{(n)}}2\mathbf{1}_{X_{(n)}>0}.
$$
